# How to add on click event in google map marker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am calling this view with a geolist containing longitude, and latitude values.

I convert it to an array.

```
var geoArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.GeoList));
```

then within loop I put those values to markers,

```
    for (var i = 0; i < geoArray.length; i++)
    {
         var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoArray[i].Latitude, geoArray[i].Longitude);
         var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng,
         map: map,
         title: geoArray[i].SubmittedBy

          });

    }
```

Now, I want to create a click event here for markers so that when I click on the **marker** I can show some information about the place. Also, on clicking I want to zoom to that place.

My full script code is :

```
<script>


                var map;
                var src = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudcreativeltd/Rail_Ex_RoW_my.kml';




                function initMap() {
                    // Map options
                    var options = {
                        zoom: 6,
                        center: { lat: 23.6850, lng: 90.3563 }
                    }
                    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                        url: 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudcreativeltd/Rail_Ex_RoW_my.kml',
                        map: map
                    });

                    // New map
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);


                    var geoArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.GeoList));

                    for (var i = 0; i < geoArray.length; i++) {
                        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoArray[i].Latitude, geoArray[i].Longitude);
                        var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            title: geoArray[i].SubmittedBy

                        });
                    }


                    markers.addListener('click', toggleBounce);

                    // Loop through markers
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
                    {
                        addMarker(markers[i]);
                    }

                    // Add Marker Function
                    function addMarker(props) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: props.coords,
                            map: map,
                            //icon:props.iconImage

                        });


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                            map.setZoom(9);
                            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                        });
                        // Check for customicon
                        if (props.iconImage) {
                            // Set icon image
                            marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
                        }

                        // Check content
                        if (props.content) {
                            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: props.content
                            });


                            //Adding KML leayer
                            var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src,
                                {
                                    suppressInfoWindows: true,
                                    preserveViewport: false,
                                    map: map
                                });
                            kmlLayer.addListener('click',
                                function(event) {
                                    var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
                                    var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
                                    testimonial.innerHTML = content;
                                });


                            marker.addListener('click',
                                function() {
                                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                });
                        }

                    }


                }
                function toggleBounce(){
                    content:hello
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you could use a closure  using a function fo create the listener in this case  the function addListenerOnMarker

```
<script>


  var map;
  var src = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudcreativeltd/Rail_Ex_RoW_my.kml';

  function initMap() {
      // Map options
      var options = {
          zoom: 6,
          center: { lat: 23.6850, lng: 90.3563 }
      }
      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudcreativeltd/Rail_Ex_RoW_my.kml',
          map: map
      });

      // New map
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);


      var geoArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.GeoList));

      var addListenerOnMarker = function(actMarker){

              actMarker.addListener('click', function() {
                  map.setZoom(9);
                  map.setCenter(actMarker.getPosition());
              });

      }

      for (var i = 0; i < geoArray.length; i++) {
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoArray[i].Latitude, geoArray[i].Longitude);
          var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              title: geoArray[i].SubmittedBy

          });
          addListenerOnMarker(markers);
      }

</script>
```

Be careful at the proper use of var and array .. in your code you don't produce an array of markers but just create (and recreate ) a single marker i have leave the name markers and the remove the not propedeutical rest of code  .. 
  (for produce an array of obeject (eg_marker) you should push the object  inside and array  . )

Comment: Is there any onclick marker function so that whenever I click on a marker It shows some information about the marker's place.

Comment: This mean that my answer  resolve your question .. for you comment you should extend the onListenerOnMarker functio passing the value you want ad add fo exampe  to an info window )

Comment: can you give me the code portion of how can I show details on clicking a marker ?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed   SO  is  not a free coding  or code finder service  ...   but a question/answer  site ..  you have question  for click event  ... and my answer  give you a solution  .. if you need  more you should post another question...  (but you could also take a brief search on google on SO for this)

Comment: I have successfully solved my problem and I know this is not a free coding service. You don't need to tell me!

Comment: !? ..I do not see any form of gratitude in your comments for helping you .. I believe that above all in these contexts respect must be at the base of everything